# remove directory in c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2005

how to remove a entire directory in c++

Comment: Removing directories isn't really part of the C++ standard. It is an Operating System operation, and can vary based on which OS you are using. Given your tags (assuming those are your tags) a better question would be "How do I remove an entire directory in C++ on Windows?"

Comment: The `windows` tag was not his

Comment: Rolled back as the `windows` tag as it indicates that windows is the sole target rather than just the primary development platform.

Comment: Well, if the VS-2005 tag was his, which I see it was, then it amounts to the same thing.

Answer (score 11):

There isn't a standard way of manipulating the filesystem in C++, so you will have to use system specific code or use a wrapper around it. For example, [Boost.Filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/filesystem/index.html).

As you indicated you are using Windows you could use the Win32 API however it is a a C API rather than a C++ API which means it is slightly more complex to use from C++. As it is Windows specific it won't work on other operating systems. In my opinion the API is not as well designed as Boost.Filesystem.

Comment: +1 Boost.Filesystem is a beautiful DSL for filesystem operations, and your code will be portable.  Definitely go for it.

Answer (score 2):

See [this code snippet](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/w-p/files/folderdirectorymaintenance/article.php/c8999/).

Comment: That's Windows only though. You might as well just use `system("rmdir folder_name");`

Comment: The question is tagged visual-studio-2005 and windows.

Comment: The `windows` tag was added by someone else, maybe the OP is developing on VS but wants to stay multiplatform

Comment: Ah, I see and apologize. I still think portability should be maintained, even if not entirely necessary, providing it doesn't come at great expense.